# "Edit the above snippet" is very small on Ask Question page in Edge

Tags: bug, design, stack-snippets

The visual appearance of *Edit the above snippet* is very small in [Edge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Edge).

**In Chrome**

[image]

It is perfect.

But

**In Edge**

[image]

#### More Details

**Edge**

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; ServiceUI 8) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.79 Safari/537.36 Edge/14.14393"
```

**Chrome**

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"
```

All the remaining links are working perfectly fine. The issue is only with this link.

Comment: This looks like a bug in Edge. I haven't tried this with a minimal test case, but it seems that Edge forces the font size of a `<sup>` element to ~70% of what you specify.

Comment: That... is not the intended use for `<sup>`.

Answer (score 4):

This is a known issue with Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge. As it doesn't actually make the edit link unusable, it's unlikely that this will be addressed on Stack Overflow's end.

Comment: link is working but want to use lens to read. no CSS available to solve this issue?

Comment: Short of [targeting older versions of IE with conditional comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804383/relative-font-size-of-sub-or-sup-and-their-descendants-in-ie/6807318#6807318), no, since you can't similarly target newer versions of IE as well as Microsoft Edge. A much more feasible - and much more sensible - solution would be to not use a sup element in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Here I have generated a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/x33h53s6/8/).

I was able to notice that `body{font-size:13px;}` is not getting applied that that changes down things to a smaller version in case of `sup` tag.

I have done few tweaks in the fiddle that helps a bit, and we can make that style conditional in case of Edge.

Or just use *Result Window* of [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/x33h53s6/8/embedded/result/).

As of 2022-11-09, this seems to be resolved in current versions of Microsoft Edge.

Comment: Zoom is 100% . all others are visible properly

Comment: With the updated fiddle it's reproducible. It's a known bug in IE (see BoltClock's comment) and apparently the bug made it all the way to Edge.